# Mongoid gives uninitialized constant Mongo

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to use mongoid but it outputs this error:

> uninitialized constant 'Mongo'

Here is my code:

```
require "mongoid"

Mongoid.configure do |config|
    config.master = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost",27017).db("arthist")
end

class Artist
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :name, type: String
end 

a = Artist.create(name: "hoge")
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What version of Mongoid are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

include gem `mongo` in your Gemfile and restart the server it should do the trick.